# Adding UIButton to UIImageView within UIScrollView on Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uibutton

I am writing an application for an event my organization is hosting using Swift. I have an image with the floor layout and want to add buttons to select locations (such as bathrooms, entrances, exits, emergency sections, etc) so that people can click them and information about the location pops up.

I currently have an imageview with the floor layout within a scrollview to allow the user to zoom in and out of the image. When I try to add buttons to the scrollview they don't stay relative to the image when zooming in and out, nor do their size change. I have tried adding constraints on to make the location stay the same when zooming in and out.

It also won't let me relocate the button on the storyboard to be a subview of the imageview. Looking up similar solutions says to add the button programmatically as a subview of the imageview but then it'd be really hard to put the 100+ buttons in the right location. Any suggestions as to how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

you have no other choice instead of adding by code.. because from code you can add as subview of image view , whereas Storyboard wont add buttons as subviews of imageView, but it will add buttons as subview of Scroll View